# Finding a metric for special open ball around $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ (with $A\neq\emptyset$ and $(0,0)\in A$).

Is it possible to find a metric $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$  which $A$ be the open ball and neighborhood for $(0,0)$ for special radius ???

Comment: Are you asking if we can define a metric on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ such that any subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ containing the element $(0,0)$ can be considered a ball around $(0,0)$ of some radius?

Comment: yes,you are right..

Comment: I think it relates to some of minkwski researches and works,but i couldn't find any thing about it ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let $r$ be the desired radius.

Define
$$d(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $x = y$}\\
r/2, &\text{if $x \ne y$ and either $x, y \in A$ or $x, y \not\in A$,}\\
r, &\text{if $x \in A$ and $y \not\in A$, or $x \not\in A$ and $y \in A$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: tnx,but let A be a shape like a triangel in the surface which contains (0,0),is it possible to make a metric that A be a open ball with the center (0,0)?

Comment: This metric works for that. I assumed by *metric*, you just meant "distance function," as in a metric space. Was I wrong?

Comment: u are right,tnx.